# wordpress different languages same element

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a strange behavior in a Wordpress site which I develop. Same text element 2 different languages.
My website is in Greek Language but some elements have both English and Greek language.
I use Elementor free. I have set in Settings -> General -> Website language to Greek.
The Theme is Astra.
In every article page, the user can post a comment. The page shows "Post a σχόλιο" where σχολιο is the greek word for comment (In English ισ "Post a comment", in Greek, "Γράψε ένα σχόλιο"). Below the post place has 1 element that is "previous αρθρο" where αρθρο is the greek word for article. 
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) to add translation to your site.